# Is Var[max{ a, min{X, b}}] <= Var[X] for a < b and X being normally distributed?

Tags: inequality, normal-distribution, variance

Given a normal random variable $X$, I define $Y \equiv$ max{ $a$, min{ $X, b$}} with $-\infty < a < b < \infty$. Then, is it true that $Var[Y] \leq Var[X]$? If so, please provide a proof. If not, please provide a counter-example.

Comment: Hints: Censored Normal. Variance = mean(conditional variance) + Var(conditional mean).

Comment: $Var[Y] = E[Var[Y|X]] + Var[E[Y|X]]  
= Var[E[Y|X]]  
= Var[a*I_{X < a} + X*I_{X \in (a,b)} + b*I_{X > b}]$  

$Var[X] = E[Var[X|Y]] + Var[E[X|Y]]  

= E[ Var[X|X<a]*I_{X < a} + Var[X|X>b]*I_{X > b} ]  
 
+ Var[ E[X|X<a]*I_{X < a} + X*I_{X \in (a,b)} + E[X|X>b]*I_{X>b} ]$

@MarkL.Stone: am I on the right track?